# Docker Image Requirements for a GitLab-CI Runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have GitLab, GitLab-CI and `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` running on different machines. I've successfully added a runner using docker and the ruby:2.1 image as detailed on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md

What I'd like to do next is have runners for a minimal Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 configured. Not knowing docker, I thought I'd try to use the `ubuntu:14.04` and `ubuntu:12.04` images. However when the start up and try to clone my project repo, they complain about `git` not being found. I then assumed that with these images, git wasn't installed. So my questions are:

- What tools need to be available in a docker image to be used "out-of-the-box" by the `gitlab-ci-multi-runner`
- Are there a set of images already available for various OS's with these already included
- Should I really be looking to create my own docker images for this purpose?

Comment: I use grunt, git, phpunit, wp-cli etc for managing my WordPress development. I couldn't find everything I needed in one container, so I made my own: https://hub.docker.com/r/wpquark/wptest-php-nodejs-grunt/ So I guess you should make your own image if you are not finding anything that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Popular base images that contain commonly used software for building software are (based on) `buildpack-deps` https://hub.docker.com/r/library/buildpack-deps/ (e. g. [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) is based on that)

In your case you could specify `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-scm` which is based on Debian Stretch and includes source code management (SCM) tools like git.

I suppose you could create a Gitlab Runner that uses these images as default. But I think **you should always specify the needed image in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`-file**.

I would **always hesitate in creating my own Docker Images**, because there are a lot [available](https://store.docker.com/search?category=base%2Cfeatured%2Cos&q=&source=verified&type=image). Still many specific ones are maintained (or better not maintained) by one person for a specific use case that often does not fit your application. The best choice would be to pick a *base*-image and only add minor `RUN` commands for the customization.